# How to use reflection to unit-test an internal (Friend in VB) class within an assembly, when the InternalsVisibleToAttribute is not an option?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, proxy, .net-2.0, internals

I have a solution with two projects within:

```
Company.Project.vbproj
Company.Project.Tests.vbproj
```

Within the `Company.Project.vbproj` assembly, I have a class `FriendClass.vb` which scope is `Friend (internal in C#)`.

Now I wish to test this `FriendClass.vb` from within the `Company.Project.Tests.vbproj` assembly. I know about the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx), but that is not an option in Visual Basic .NET 2.0, as it is only available with C#, in .NET 2.0 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827551/unit-testing-using-internalsvisibletoattribute-requires-compiling-with-outfilen)).

I would like to create myself a proxy class using this internal *FriendClass* from within my testing assembly, so that I could instantiate it and do the testings accordingly.

**Any idea or known practices to do so?**

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround that I have found is one used back in .NET Framework 1.1.

As the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` is not useable in .NET 2.0 Visual Basic, the only workaround that I have found is to include my tests within the same project as my library itself. Besides, some further work needs to be accomplished.

1. Create yourself a new compilation CONFIG called "Tests" (that is where you may select "Release"/"Debug");
2. Create a new folder named "Tests" within your project;
3. Add a new class, the one to test your Friend (internal in C#) members;
4. First line of code within this class should be: `#if CONFIG = "Tests" then ... #end if`;
5. Place your code between this compiler IF directive.

For example, if I have the following Friend class:

```
Friend Class MyFactory
    Friend Property Property1 As Object
        Get
            Return _field1
        End Get
        Set (ByVal value As Object)
            _field1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Sub SomeSub(ByVal param1 As Object)
        ' Processing here...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, if you want to test this class in .NET 2.0 Visual Basic, you will need to create a test class within the same project where the `MyFactory` class sits. This class should look like so:

```
#If CONFIG = "Tests" Then

    Imports NUnit.Framework

    <TestFixture()> _
    Public Class MyFactoryTests
        <Test()> _
        Public Sub SettingProperty1Test
            ' Doing test here...
        End Sub
    End Class

#End If
```

Since you have a compiler directive telling the compiler to compile and to include this class only when the "Tests" CONFIG is selected, you won't get this class on "Debug" or on "Release" mode. This class won't even be part of the library, this for not polluting your library unnecessarily, and this allows you to test your Friend class anyway.

That is the smartest way I have found to work around this issue in Visual Basic .NET 2.0.

Comment: That looks sound to me. Merely 9 years have passed; is there any other workaround? I'm surprised your post did not get more attention!

Comment: Testing at that time was not as well known as it is these days. As this made it, I never looked for an even more clever way to achieve it, as I most code in .Net Core 2.2 and .Net 4.7 nowadays.

Comment: It appears the InternalsVisibleToattribute is now available with VB.Net too!

Comment: I'd believe so, since from VS2010 (which wasn't available or not used by my client at the time of posting) MS did a tremendous effort to upgrade and bring back "from the deads" VB.NET and make it as feature-rich as C# - or near enough. This attribute is actually useful. Besides, with a folder structure such as a src for source code and test for test code, this makes it even simpler using the same namespace as the assembly under test. This is an even smarter way to do it. I just don't know if it would have worked back in the day.